# TimePicker и системное время

Tags: java, android, время

Сделал собственную разметку и добавил виджет TimePicker и кнопку,которая будет сбрасывать время до текущего время системы.

Ситуация такая, я изменяю в самом виджете время на иное, и нажимаю кнопку, чтобы восстановить системное время, но время восстанавливается некорректно

1. Восстанавливается только час, минуты остаются которые я выбрал сам
2. Если подождать когда пройдет минута, а именно после 59 секунды, то минуты при нажатии на кнопку вернутся к правильным системным
3. Кнопка работает только один раз, если я хоть один раз сбросил время по нажатию кнопки, то если я снова изменю в виджете время, оно больше не будет сбрасываться по нажатию кнопки

---

```
public void setCurrentTimeClick(View v){
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int min = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int sec = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    mTimePicker.setCurrentHour(hour);
    mTimePicker.setCurrentMinute(min);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Тост просто для проверки, я не могу понять в чем дело, ведь минуты часы и секунды отлично считываются через c.get, подтверждение тому корректный вывод через тост, но сам виджет сбросит до текущего системного времени адекватно не получается

Comment: То есть минуты он не может обновить пока не начнется новая минута, я так понимаю если час подождать то часы он тоже обновит, скорее всего так и задумано, и час он сможет обновить только начнется новый час суток

Comment: Многое непонятно в описании, особенно 3 пункт, распишите подробнее ваши действия и ожидания. Ну и для начала уберите final перед Calendar.